# Identity column is increasing but data is not getting inserted

Tags: jquery, asp.net, sql-server, ajax

I am trying to insert data from ajax jQuery call from front end. when query executes no error is coming. and in database identity column is getting increased but even data is not there. Not sure if it's not getting inserted or what? When I try to edit rows in table, I can identity column is increasing. Any solution?

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO TrackChanges VALUES(@TagID, @Action, @Date, @UserID, @Content, @DomainName)"))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TagID", "lbl1");
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Action", ChangesInfo.Title);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", ChangesInfo.Timestamp);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", ChangesInfo.Author);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Content", ChangesInfo.Content);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DomainName", "IBG");

        cmd.Connection = con;

        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Try execute the insert directly on your db. Maybe you have a trigger on that table

Comment: What do you mean by the autoinc column value is increased but the data is not there? do you mean you just insert `NULL`s? Do you have a trigger on that table?

Comment: i didn't have any trigger

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved. Length of one of my DB column was low so data was getting truncated. I got confused because it wasn't throwing any relevant error.

Thanks.